# How to multiply the numbers 0 to 150 by the same value?

Tags: python, list, numpy, matplotlib

I have a Problem with my Python exercise.

Here is the part of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
import loaddataa as ld

dataListStride = ld.loadData("../Data/Fabienne")
indexStrideData = 0 
strideData = dataListStride[indexStrideData]

def horizontal(yAngle, yAcceleration, xAcceleration):
    a = (m.cos(yAngle)*yAcceleration)-(m.sin(yAngle)*xAcceleration)
    return a

resultsHorizontal = list()

for i in range (len(strideData)):
    strideData_yAngle = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 2]
    strideData_xAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 4]
    strideData_yAcceleration= strideData.to_numpy()[i, 5]
    resultsHorizontal.append(horizontal(strideData_yAngle, strideData_yAcceleration, strideData_xAcceleration))

print("The Values are: " +str(resultsHorizontal))

plt.plot(resultsHorizontal)

print(len(resultsHorizontal))
```

And the code of loaddataa.py:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def loadData(relativPath):
    files = os.listdir(relativPath)
    path = os.path.abspath(relativPath)
    datas = list()
    for file in files:
        absPath = path + "/" + file
        print(absPath)
        data = pd.read_csv(absPath)
        datas.append(data)
    return datas
```

With the Calculation of `def horizontal` I get many values in the end. With `print(len(resultsHorizontal))` I know how many values there are. In this example or with the CSV read in here, I get 150 values. 
The plot looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krhHr.png)

As you can see the x-axis consists of the values 0 to 150, because there are 150 calculated values in the list by the CSV . I would like to calculate every single value on the x-axis multiplied by 0.01. So that the calculation looks like this: 0 * 0.01= 0, 1*0.01=0.01, 2*0.01=0.02, .... , 20*0.01=0.2 ,.... ,149*0.01=1.49, 150*0.01=1.5. The values after the = should then be on the x-axis.
There is also an other problem. It shall be independent of 150, because  because it can happen that there are more or less than 150 values. This depends on the imported CSV file. I hope it's clear what my problem is. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to scale the x-axis values. 
Your code for plotting doesn't explicitly specify an x-axis. `plt.plot(resultsHorizontal)`

You could do something like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scale_factor = 0.01
x_values = np.arange(len(resultsHorizontal)) * scale_factor
plt.plot(x_values, resultsHorizontal)
```

And if you wanted to prevent matplotlib from automatically re-scaling the x-axis to fit your squeezed signal:

```
plt.xlim([0, len(resultsHorizontal)])
```

Otherwise matplotlib will adjust the x-axis to fit the data.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is a numpy array then you can literally just multiply it by 0.01 to get the result, but if you want to keep it as a python list for some reason, then a simple list comprehension solves this quite easily.

```
new_ret = [0.01 * value for value in resultsHorizontal]
```

`